# Sorting a list with a hash table lookup

Tags: redis

I have a list of groups with IDs stored in a hash table that I would like to sort using a matching hash table of votes.  The data is in the format:

```
RPUSH group groupA
RPUSH group groupB
RPUSH group groupC

HSET g:1 group: groupA
HSET g:2 group: groupB
HSET g:3 group: groupC

HINCRBY groupVotes g:1 2
HINCRBY groupVotes g:2 3
HINCRBY groupVotes g:3 1
```

If I query `red:lrange('group', 0, 2)` I get back `{'groupA', 'groupB', 'groupC'}`

How can I sort this list by groupVotes descending to return `{'groupB', 'groupA', 'groupC'}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `groupVotes` was a **zset** you could use an algorithm like:

```
$keys = `zrevrange groupVotes 0 2`
$list = []
for($key in keys)
 $list.push(`hget $key group:')
$list
```

That way you don't need RPUSH. Even better, if the zset had directly the **group names** instead of the key name member the command `zrange groupVotes 0 2` would be enough!

Nonetheless for the exercise I translated the above algorithm in LUA (still using groupVotes as a zset):

```
local a = {}
local keys = redis.call('zrevrange', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]);
for i, name in ipairs(keys) do
  table.insert(a, redis.call('hget', name, 'group:'))
end
return a
```

Save it in `test.lua` and then run

```
$ redis-cli --eval test.lua groupVotes , 0 2
1) "groupB"
2) "groupA"
3) "groupC"
```

Now you just have to use it inside your code with the [**EVAL**](http://redis.io/commands/eval) and [**EVALSHA**](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha) (requires Redis 2.6+) commands.

**Note**: It's way better to use LUA here to remove network roundtrip due to the algorithm.

Comment: Aha, ZSETs!  I hadn't gotten that far down in the documentation yet.  My RPUSH list / HSET of groups isn't set in stone.  So, it looks like it would be much more efficient to store the vote data in a ZSET with ZINCRBYs.  I'll try this tomorrow.